# WPF DataGrid DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemsSource Referenced Off DataGrid.ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I have a DataGrid like below

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False">
     <DataGrid.Columns>
          <DataGridTextColumn Header="Col1" Binding="{Binding Col1}" IsReadOnly="True" />
          <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Col2" ItemsSource="{Binding Col2}" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Selected}" />
     </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The values that end up in Col1 are actually `Window.DataContext.Collection[index].Col1`, but WPF seems to be looking for Col2's ItemsSource at `Window.DataContext.Col2`. The actual path I need is `Window.DataConext.Collection[index].Col2`

Please note the reference to `index` above is not to a static value but to the fact that each row gets a value from one of the collection items.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Col2"  SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Selected}" 
                        ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                                                                             AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, 
                                              Path=DataContext.Collection[index].Col2}" />
```

Poor formatting. (insert a number for `index`)

Comment: I should have made that a little clearer: index is the row basically each item in the collection becomes a row of data, and the proper values for for that combo box are different for each row of data. The index isn't a static value.